# is it possible to study MBA after B.tech and phd on electronics after MBA

Tags: education

Hi every one I'm full confused about my future please give a good suggestions,
Currently I am working on Ebedded systems(yocto and embedded linux)
I have completed my batchulor of technology in electronics and communications(4 years) in 2015.
so now I want to study MBA after this can I do P.hd in electronics side.
is am i thinking wrong?

Comment: Why not do the PhD and MBA simultaneously?  Kinda seems like a waste of time to do them one-at-a-time.  Alternatively, you could do the PhD first and then do the MBA on the side while working.

Comment: you mean can do phd after B.tech with out P.g. is it possibple

Comment: It may depend on where you're at.  In the United States, yes, someone with a Bachelor's can apply directly to a PhD program.  The PhD program will begin by having the student earn a Master's.

Comment: (Practically) anything is possible. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a PhD, you don't need to do an MBA.

If you want to get a PhD in the United States, then either:

1. You first earn an MS, MSc, MA, or MEng, then apply to a PhD program.
2. You apply directly to a PhD program without any graduate degree, then the graduate program basically has you earn a Master's degree before you start the typical PhD work.

MBA's are Master's degrees, but they're more focused on *Business Management*.  You might choose to earn an MBA before, during, or after your PhD, but it's not necessary.  MBA's and PhD's aren't very much related.

Comment: you mean if i do MBA I can not able to do PHD am right?

Comment: @Sivanageswararao.Vadalasetti You can get both if you like.

Comment: Thanks @Nat ,just assume I compiled my bTech and MBA Now can I do PHD in electronics.

Comment: @Sivanageswararao.Vadalasetti Yes, that is possible.  You don't _need_ to get an MBA before you start your PhD, but you _can_ get an MBA before you start your PhD.  Just so you know, the PhD program will still have you earn a Master's in _Electronics_ before you can do the PhD in _Electronics_, so you will effectively have to earn 2 Master's degrees.

Comment: @Sivanageswararao.Vadalasetti My advice is for typical education in the United States, but it may be different in other countries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72527/discussion-between-sivanageswararao-vadalasetti-and-nat).